# how do I retrieve data value 0-1 and show in Radiobuttonlist as name

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, radiobuttonlist

I need to write a code to retrieve data from Sqlserver DATABASE

That data is value from the field called: `NewProducer`. It contains 0 - 1.

I need to retrieve and show them in `Radiobuttonlist`.

The value is:

> ```
> 0 = "Ex Producer"
> 1 = "New Producer"
> ```

I write a code like this

```
     RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(convertInteger(dt.Rows(0)("NewProducer"))).Selected = True
```

from `Producer` Table

when I compiled it show just a 0 and 1 in the radio button list

I got stuck that I can't change the radio button list to show "Ex Producer" and "New Producer" Replace the 0 and 1

Comment: pretty vague question...well, it's not even a question. Have you tried something so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I got stuck on my radiobuttonlist just show ๐ = 0 ๐ = 1

I need them to show ๐ = Ex Producer ๐ = New Producer

that retrieve data from Database

Comment: can you post your code what you have tried

Comment: RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(convertInteger(dt.Rows(0)("NewProducer"))).Selected = True

Comment: convertInteger is a function

Comment: @TouchyVivace if you don't improve your question by adding more details we won't know what to answer...meaning, you won't get any answers

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you I will do my best on next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050794/databinding-of-radiobuttonlist-using-selectedvalue-possible) can help you.

[Databinding of RadioButtonList using SelectedValue...possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050794/databinding-of-radiobuttonlist-using-selectedvalue-possible)

I think if you have only those two values, you can declare them in the aspx page itself like below:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Ex Producer" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="New Producer" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

After that in code behind you can use your code:

```
ListItem item = RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByValue(ConvertToInteger(dt.Rows[0]["NewProducer"].ToString();
if(item != null)
item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: One Tip: Do not use datasets in UI. Pass your Business Objects or Entities to the UI if posible. This will inhance its maintanence and testability.