# RadioButtonList selected value binding in aspx

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I got this `RadioButtonList` with defined `ListItems`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RblSpouseLocation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Text="In Country" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Outside of Country" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I have a field "`SpouseLocation`" of type `bit` in my database. I need to bind the selected value of the `RadioButtonList` to this field.

I found tutorials of how to do it in the code-behind, but can it be done in `aspx` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my database field type to int and added "SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SpouseLocation") %>" to my radiobuttonlist

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050794/databinding-of-radiobuttonlist-using-selectedvalue-possible) questions helped me