# RadioButtonList inside Repeater bound to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have radiobuttonlist inside Repeater and  this is my code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="quesitons" DataSourceID="quest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label CssClass="questionlabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("question") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="answerlist" CssClass="radiostyle" runat="Server" DataSourceID="quest">
                <asp:ListItem Text='<%#Eval("answer1") %>' Value='<%#Eval("id")%>-<%#Eval("answer1")%>'></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text='<%#Eval("answer2") %>' Value='<%#Eval("id")%>-<%#Eval("answer2")%>'></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text='<%#Eval("answer3") %>' Value='<%#Eval("id")%>-<%#Eval("answer3")%>'></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text='<%#Eval("answer4") %>' Value='<%#Eval("id")%>-<%#Eval("answer4")%>'></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When it run it gives this error :

> "Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a
>   DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem does not have a
>   DataBinding event "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Databinding of RadioButtonList using SelectedValue...possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050794/databinding-of-radiobuttonlist-using-selectedvalue-possible)

Comment: remove the datasourceid attribute in the radiobuttonlist and check

Comment: it still the same i think it means some thing like datasource is not recognized in the radiobuttonlist