# Exception "The name 'BindItem' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, strong-typing

I'm recently found out that you can use "BindItem" and "Item" directly in the markup of an aspx page in the context of databound controls like GridView or DetailsView (by specifying the `ItemType` attribute). What I'm trying to achieve now is inline comparison of members such as:

```
    <asp:RadioButton Text="All Assigned" ID="rb1" 
         Checked='<%# BindItem.AllAssigned %>' 
         runat="server" GroupName="AllAssigned" />
    <asp:RadioButton Text="Responsible only"  ID="rb2" 
         Checked='<%# !BindItem.AllAssigned %>' 
         runat="server" GroupName="AllAssigned" />
```

In this situation I need Two-Way-Binding, so i choose the BindItem expression.
But it seems that expressions like `!BindItem.AllAssigned` or `BindItem.AllAssigned == false` are not working in Markup. They are giving me exceptions like

**The name 'BindItem' does not exist in the current context**

or

**DataBinding: DataContext.MyEntity does not contain a property with the name  'false'.**

What do I have to write for such expressions?

Comment: Probably you should use `Eval`, e.g. `<%# !(bool)Eval("BindItem.AllAssigned") %>`.

Comment: I need Two-Way-Binding in this situation.

Comment: Are you want two-way binding like `Bind()`? I don't think you can use `Bind()` with conditional operators, `Bind()` only accepts field names. You need to handle `CheckedChanged` event to retrieve negated value, or use `RadioButtonList` to handle different radio button state.

Comment: My current approach is to use **Item** instead of **BindItem** and handling the Updating event of the LinqDataSource to determine which radiobutton was ticked. But this is quite inconvenient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use logical negation operator with databinding expression, you can use `Eval()` or `DataBinder.Eval()` inside data binding expression to use it, like example below:

```html
<%-- alternative 1 --%>
<asp:RadioButton Text="Responsible only"  ID="rb2" 
         Checked='<%# !(bool)Eval("AllAssigned") %>' 
         runat="server" GroupName="AllAssigned" />

<%-- alternative 2 --%>
<asp:RadioButton Text="Responsible only"  ID="rb2" 
         Checked='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AllAssigned")) %>' 
         runat="server" GroupName="AllAssigned" />
```

If you want to enable two-way binding, instead using separate radio buttons with different IDs, use `RadioButtonList` with `Bind()` set in `SelectedValue` property as in example below:

```html
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AllAssigned") %>' RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ...>
    <asp:ListItem Text="All Assigned" Value="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Responsible only" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then you can retrieve selected radio button value using `rb.SelectedValue`.

Related issue: [Databinding of RadioButtonList using SelectedValue...possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050794/databinding-of-radiobuttonlist-using-selectedvalue-possible)

Comment: Yes that worked for me. But I had to write True and False (uppercase) in the ListItems